# Can't Install Geopandas

Tags: python, installation, conda, geopandas, forge

I'm currently working with Python 3.7.6 with Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook.
I used to work with geopandas like 1 week ago with no problems.
Then I tried to install osmnx and it took forever, more than 10 hours, so I interrupted it. I had to continue working on other stuff, then I tried installation a few more times then I get a trac issue that I couldn't fix, so I re-installed Anaconda 2 days ago. Thereafter I tried to install geopandas and I had this issue, I run the code and never finish the installation, more than 10 hours, and interrupted it.

I tried the both codes below:

`conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas`

`!conda install geopandas`

I installed successfully other modules like Folium with no problems
`conda install -c conda-forge folium`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try installing dependencies one by one to figure out which one is causing the issue? https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#dependencies

Answer (score 3):

Both geopandas and OSMnx have dependencies that can result in a complicated install. Easiest to install in a clean, isolated conda environment.

Install geopandas:

```
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n gpd --strict-channel-priority geopandas
```

Install osmnx per [its docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#installation):

```
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx
```

Comment: Having Anaconda users add `conda-forge` as the highest priority channel in their global settings usually makes it near impossible to work with the **base** environment going forward. Would be better to recommend an *ad hoc* channel change or create an empty environment and set environment-specific channel settings using `conda config --env`.